# Adding custom M Codes to Marlin

Tags: marlin

If I wanted to add my own custom M Codes in Marlin - in which source code file would I do that?

Comment: This answer is relevant for Marlin 1.x, but not for Marlin 2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file `Marlin_main.cpp` on line 7131 there is a switch case:

(To turn on line numbers go to `File>Preferences` and click Display line numbers.)

```
case 'M': switch (codenum) {
  #if ENABLED(ULTIPANEL)
    case 0: // M0 - Unconditional stop - Wait for user button press on LCD
    case 1: // M1 - Conditional stop - Wait for user button press on LCD
      gcode_M0_M1();
      break;
  #endif // ULTIPANEL

  case 17:
    gcode_M17();
    break;
  etc.....
```

Adding another case with an unused number such as 5 and then the code you want followed by a break should do the trick. Ex:

```
case 5:
   doABunchofCoolStuff();
   myservo.write(thebestposition);
   break;
```

-AC